# How to create a actual interactive checkbox inside table cell in xslt

Tags: xslt, checkbox, xslt-1.0

I am new to the XSLT world. Please find my query below:
The task before me is to create a docx report using XSL and XSLT.
This report should contain a table with some static data inside it.

In this table, The requirement is to have an interactive checkbox in each row and then some static text. Below is the screenshot of the expected result
[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSoCB.png)

The input XML file looks like the below:

```
<AdvancedReport>
    <Name>Main Report</Name>
    <Description>Main Report</Description> 

 <Stylesheet>tvc:stylesheet:Main_Report/Main_Report.xslt</Stylesheet>    
    <OutputFormat>DOCX</OutputFormat>
<Settings>
    <Setting name="createAsSuperUser" value="true"/>
    <Setting name="fileOnDemand" value="true"/>
    <Setting name="useLatestFOP" value="true"/>
    <Setting name="outputHandlers" value="checkin"/>
    <Setting name="checkin.create.object">false</Setting>
    <Setting name="checkin.format">generic</Setting>
    <Setting name="checkin.unlock">true</Setting>
    <Setting name="checkin.append">false</Setting>
    <Setting name="file.prefix" value="${NAME}_${REV}"/>
    <Setting name="meta.select.id" value="$&lt;id&gt;"/>
    <Setting name="meta.select.name" value="$&lt;name&gt;"/>
    <Setting name="meta.select.type" value="$&lt;type&gt;"/>
    <Setting name="meta.select.rev" value="$&lt;revision&gt;"/>
    <Setting name="meta.select.status" value="$&lt;current&gt;"/>
    <Setting name="meta.select.title" value="$&lt;attribute[Title].value&gt;"/>
    <Setting name="meta.select.reviewMeetingDate" value="$&lt;attribute[MHC_ReviewMeetingDate].value&gt;"/>     
</Settings> 

</AdvancedReport>
```

We have an in-house tool at our org which uses XML file to fetch data from a web app and create a report based on it.
The 'Setting' tags in above code gets the data from the application.
The XML also has a reference to the XSLT file to design the report structure. (Main_report.xslt in this case)

The Main_Report.xslt called from the above code looks like below. The table below in xslt does not depend on the XML for input. We write all the data inside XSLT <fo:block> manually.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
     xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.0">

    <xsl:preserve-space elements="block" />
    <xsl:include href="stylesheet:DocumentReportHeader.xslt" /> 

    <xsl:template name="page1">
        <xsl:param name="meta-data" select="''" />
        <xsl:param name="objRev" select="''" />
        <fo:table margin-top="10pt" border="0.5pt solid #000000">
        <fo:table-column column-width="75%" />
        <fo:table-column column-width="25%" />                  
        <fo:table-body border="0.5pt solid #000000">                    
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell border="0.5pt solid #000000" font-weight="normal">
                    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="regularTextChar">  &#x2610; This is the Line1
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>                        
                    <fo:table-cell border="0.5pt solid #000000" font-weight="normal">
                    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="regularTextChar"></fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                        </fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-cell border="0.5pt solid #000000" font-weight="normal">
                    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="regularTextChar">☐ 
 This is the Line 2
                    </fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
                <fo:table-cell border="0.5pt solid #000000" font-weight="normal">
                    <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="regularTextChar"></fo:block>
                </fo:table-cell>
            </fo:table-row>                 
        </fo:table-body>
        </fo:table>`
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tried adding it using the UNICODE character `<&#x2610;>` (in first fo: block for Line 1) or a direct symbol ☐ (in Line 2 of the above code).
However, this added just the checkbox symbol and not an actual interactive checkbox.

Please help here.

Comment: Please share an minmal appropriate peace of your source xml

Comment: Hi @SiebeJongebloed, updated the bare necessary XML.
Note: The table in xslt does not depend on the XML for input. We write all the data inside XSLT <fo: block> manually

Comment: You need to share the xml that is the source for xslt

Comment: You are creating an output document using the XSLFO vocabulary. Do you know what XSLFO elements you want to create? If you do, then tell us; and this becomes an XSLT problem. But if you don't know what XSLFO elements you want to create, then this is an XSLFO question not an XSLT question; once you know what output you want your XSLT to produce, writing the XSLT code should be easy.

Comment: You are using XSL-FO to create a .docx document??

Comment: Which software do you use to get from XML via XSL-FO and XSLT to docx?

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, Martin Honnen, I am using my company's own product libraries named 'TVC Report Generator' to create reports using XML and XSLT.

Comment: Hi @MichaelKay, apologies for the confusion in question as I am new to the XSLT world. 
Coming back to your question: The XSLT file has the XSLFO elements but I can't paste the complete code here due to organisational constraints. 
But yes, I am using the XSLFO elements to generate reports which includes some text and tables. As of now, I am stuck on creating a table with checkboxes in each row. Hence, I  pasted only the table related code.

I have updated the code above. Could you please let me know if this is sufficient?

Comment: If you want to use XSL FO to create a PDF that has PDF Acroform form fields, then your XSL FO engine needs to support creating them. TVC uses Apache FOP I believe so review their documentation for the extensions required to create Acroforms.

Comment: Hello All, I got confirmation from the TVC Team that interactive checkboxes are not possible in DOCX-type report using our OOTB TVC code. So, we changed our requirement from interactive to normal checkbox. Hence the issue is no longer needed now.  @KevinBrown